# Setting up Squarespace Developer account with Github

Tags: git, github, squarespace

I am trying to set up my new Squarespace Developer site with my Github account.

I've followed [Squarespace's guide](http://developers.squarespace.com/using-git) on doing this, but I continue to receive errors whenever I try to commit or publish. I have made some test changes to my files for testing, but Github still comes back with "Error calculating diff."

I believe I cloned the repo correctly because it's [showing up in my file-system](http://cl.ly/image/1q0H092I2z2q) - but I'm still not able to publish it to the web.

*[This image](http://cl.ly/image/3s221R2M1M0y) shows the errors that Github has come back with.*

My question is this: **How can I make my Squarespace developer account to work with Github?** I would like to be able to make changes and commit and have them immediately go live on my site.

Comment: Sorry for the "unclear what you are asking" close votes. What you are asking is cristal clear... for anyone actually knowing about git and GitHub, and taking the time to *look* at the picture you mention.

Comment: I updated my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: Somewhat, but not really, I set my repo location to where I'm pulling my Squarespace Repo from. But now It's not pushing to GitHub: http://cl.ly/image/11282I311m46

Comment: Do yu have added file to your local index as I mentioned? What does `git remote -v` show you (in command line, when you are in your repo folder)

Answer (score 2):

[From your screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/3s221R2M1M0y), it looks like you didn't add anything to the index in order to make a commit.

That is why:

- `git commit` returns `nothing to commit, working directory clean`.
- `git push` would always reports "`Everything up-to-date`"

As mentioned in the [Squarespace guide](http://developers.squarespace.com/using-git), you need to change a file content:

> Then you’ll need to add the files you want Git to track for this commit.

```
git add site.region
```

> Then you’ll need to commit your changes
>   And, finally, push the changes to your site.

[image: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/img/trees.png]

[This guide](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) can help you understand the basic git operations.

Answer (score 0):

Firts add those file on which you changed .
cmd - git add 'fname.region'
and came back to main directory and and commit your site.region file

using cmd- git commit -m add 'site.region'
and push that file
git push